# echo single value from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I've been driving myself mad with this for the last hour. It should be so easy but I just cannot work it out:

All I am trying to do is echo 1 value (in column "active") from a mysql table where the column "name" is equal to "GSHP".

This is what I have. Can anyone please help?

```
$query = "SELECT active FROM discount WHERE name = GSHP";

        $result = mysql_query($query);

        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        echo $row['active'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL you need to fit string literals into quotes. Your query should look like:

```
$query = "SELECT active FROM discount WHERE name = 'GSHP'";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Thats one problem solved but it is still not working.

Comment: @MichaelWalkling what does `mysql_error()` output? (after the query)

Comment: then there is no error anymore. maybe just just didn't notcie that everything is correct?

Comment: The problem is that "echo $row['active'];" is producing no information.

Comment: @MichaelWalkling sorry, I can only help you in errors when you post the necessary information.